# SSL connect error error 35 in paypal curl request

Tags: php, curl, paypal, ssl-certificate

When i am making a payment in paypal, its throws "SSL connect error (35)", even i have a enabled TLS. And also i have tested with "https://tlstest.paypal.com", is also return same error.

Following sample i used to test TLS.

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://tlstest.paypal.com');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 6); // CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_2
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO,  'cacert.pem');
$result = curl_exec($ch);
echo 'result = '.$result.'<br>';
echo 'errno = '.curl_errno($ch).'<br>';
echo 'error = '.curl_error($ch).'<br>';
curl_close($ch);
```

Thanks in advance